# ActionMailer with Rails: Missing template user_mailer/welcome with "mailer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I get this error in my console when I run `UserMailer.welcome.deliver_now`

```
irb(main):002:0> UserMailer.welcome.deliver_now
UserMailer#welcome: processed outbound mail in 0.7ms
/Users/jlandis/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionmailer-7.0.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:1001:in `each_template': Missing template user_mailer/welcome with "mailer". (ActionView::MissingTemplate)

Searched in:
  * "user_mailer"
```

I'm not sure what missing template means.

in app/mailers I have `application_mailer.rb`:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"
  layout "mailer"
end
```

in app/user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def welcome
    @greeting = "Hi"
    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
  
end
```

My views file path looks like this (not sure if this is relevant to the problem):
`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`
`app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb`
`app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb`

This is my first time using Ruby and I've used these two guides:

- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/your-ultimate-guide-to-sending-email-in-rails-7-d743cdad88b
- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

The templates in `app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb` and `app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb` are general layout templates like the `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` for normal view. That means they should only provide an outer, general layout/structure. And then there are more specific templates for each view. Because a homepage, a list of items or a page with a form are very different.

Same with mailer views. They provide an outer structure for all emails, like a header with a logo and a footer with some details about your company. But each mailer needs a specialized view too, because the email after sign up of a user is different to an email about a sale.

In your example, there are missing the following views:

- `app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb` and
- `app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.text.erb`

Which could look like this:

```
# app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.text.erb
<h1><%= @greeting %>,</h1>
<p>Example Email Body</p>

# app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.text.erb
<%= @greeting %>,

Example Email Body
```

Comment: Thanks @spickermann! Unfortunately, when I added these views, I got the error `method missing` for the welcome method. I needed to restart my machine because of terminal issues and now I have the error `uninitialized constant UserMailer (NameError)`.

Comment: Moving your mailer from `app/user_mailer.rb` to `app/mailers/user_mailer.rb` should fix that.

Comment: The mailer was in the `app/views/user_mailer` -- moving it to `app/views/mailer` throws the same error. Moving mailers out of `views` did not solve it.

Comment: I didn't suggest moving the mailer view files, but to move the file that contains the `UserMailer` class, which according to your question lives in `app/user_mailer.rb`, but should be placed at `app/mailers/user_mailer.rb`